# Creative Commons 3 - can I make a rework, with copyright?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

Have I to share my work (which consisted and based on CC 3.0 materials) with same license?  I am ok to put links to CC 3.0 meaterials I've used, but have I to make my work also CC 3.0 for others?

Let's divide into 2 questions:

1) If I make a video, where only video is got from CC source, but audio is my property/product, and If I mix them, can I put copyright notice only for audio?

2) If I make 10 minute video, where only 2-3 minute part was CC video, cant I make whole video copyrighted (except those 2-3 minutes... placing that note in description)?

`In CC 3.0, there is stated:`

> No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

Comment: *I want to make a commercial material, that I dont want to share for free and dont want people to reuse ...* Seems hypocritical to me - "Don't steal my stuff while I steal yours." If you are using the work inside another work that adds value and/or is transformative, that would be one thing, repackaging someone else's work for sale is a whole other matter. If that is what you are doing then I would suggest from a moral stand-point that you not. License and legality not-with-standing. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc despite offering an answer, I fully agree.  But it takes a while for people with stars in their eyes to learn to share what has been shared with them (me included!).

Comment: @Steve You and I are living in different times... however, this is not new. Not when you consider all the spammers over the past decades. Cheers!!

Comment: So I have to license my work with free CC 3.0 right? Ok, guys,thanks!   Good advises.

Comment: There is no "CC 3.0" license. Do you mean CC BY 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out this page https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ that I found by searching for *CC3 reuse of work* you will see that:

> You are free to:
>
> Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
>   **Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose,
>   even commercially**. The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long
>   as you follow the license terms.

However, as it is stated further down the page, you must give appropriate credit

**[EDIT]** On re-reading your question I am not sure I am answering it.  You want to know if you can share your work commercially with no CC3 license if it contains others' CC3 works

As you have no doubt noticed, reading and understanding CC3 licensing is not for the faint of heart.

[This](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-use-effective-technological-measures-such-as-drm-when-i-share-cc-licensed-material) likely does answer the question though

> When you receive material under a Creative Commons license, you may
>   not place additional terms and conditions on the reuse of the work .

But it is more complex than that, check out other answers on that FAQ page.

Comment: What I've understand from all of these, to be short: I have to allow people to use my work with CC 3.0 license, right?

Comment: I am no expert in the field, but that is my understanding.  If you use CC licensed work, you can't further restrict the licensing.

Comment: I've reworded something in question. Thanks for answer!